# Query by form (ala Microsoft Access) but using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ms-access, user-interface

I have a database based website application, and I would like to allow users to be able to create their own custom queries, using a tool like microsoft access's [query by form](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/examples-of-query-criteria-HA010066611.aspx).

However,I want to provide this functionality over the web. I would like to provide my users with a similar frontend over the web - I'm guessing using jQuery etc. However, before I get started, I wanted to check if something (preferably open source) already exists - if none exists, then can someone (preferably who has done something similar), provide me with the guideline steps on how to do something like this?

I must point out that I am more concerned on how to reproduce the GUI look, feel and behaviour rather than getting data to/from the server (which I can easily do on my own).

So the question again is: If I have to build a similar looking screen with similar GUI functionality, what are the outline steps I need to carry out?, and will I require any other technologies other than those mentioned here?

Ideally ofcourse, I will not have to "roll my own" and instead something similar exists (if even in non-working state), that I can use/extend.

PS: I am running a LAMP stack, so a Microsoft solution is not an option.

Comment: You would still have to do it in a server side language, to extract tables etc? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for something very similar as a front end to a MYSQL database - I have only really found the following open source example : http://ksistem.com/jquery/sqlbuilderdemo.htm